# awk: split file by column name and add header row to each file

Tags: text-processing, awk, split

I have a pipe delimited file `a.txt` which includes a header row. The first column holds a filename.

I would like to split `a.txt` into several different files - the name of which is determined by the first column. I would also like to have the header row of `a.txt` repeated at the top of each file .

so I have `a.txt`:

```
filename|count|age
1.txt|1|15
1.txt|2|14
2.txt|3|1
41.txt|44|1
2.txt|1|3
```

and I want to create `1.txt`

```
filename|count|age
1.txt|1|15
1.txt|2|14
```

and `2.txt`

```
filename|count|age
2.txt|3|1
2.txt|1|3
```

and `41.txt`

```
filename|count|age
41.txt|44|1
```

I have a basic split working

```
awk -F\| '{print>$1}' a.txt
```

but I am struggling to work out how to get the header included, could anybody help? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution would be to store the header in a separate variable and print it on the first occurence of a new `$1` value (=file name):

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR==1{hdr=$0;next} {if (!seen[$1]++) print hdr>$1; print>$1}' a.txt
```

- This will store the entire first line of `a.txt` in a variable `hdr` but otherwise leave that particular line unprocessed.
- On all subsequent lines, we first check if the `$1` value (=the desired output filename) was already encountered, by looking it up in an array `seen` which holds an occurence count of the various `$1` values. If the counter is still zero for the current `$1` value, output the header to the file indicated by `$1`, then increase the counter to suppress header output for all later occurences. The rest you already figured out yourself.

**Addendum:**

If you have more than one input file, which all have a header line, you can simply place them all as arguments to the `awk` call, as in

```
awk -F'|' ' ... ' a.txt b.txt c.txt ...
```

If, however, only the first file has a header line, you would need to change `FNR` to `NR` in the first rule.

**Caveat**

As noted by Ed Morton, the simple approach only works if the number of different output files is small (max. around 10). GNU `awk` will still continue working, but become slower due to automatically closing and opening files in the background as needed; other `awk` implementations may simply fail due to "too many open files".

Answer (score 3):

This will work robustly and  efficiently using any awk, sort, and cut:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {print (NR>1), $1, NR, $0}' "$@" |
sort -t'|' -k1,1n -k2,2 -k3,3n |
cut -d'|' -f4- |
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
    NR == 1 { hdr = $0; next }
    $1 != prev {
        close(prev)
        print hdr " > " $1
        prev = $1
    }
    { print $0 " > " $1 }
'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh a.txt
filename|count|age > 1.txt
1.txt|1|15 > 1.txt
1.txt|2|14 > 1.txt
filename|count|age > 2.txt
2.txt|3|1 > 2.txt
2.txt|1|3 > 2.txt
filename|count|age > 41.txt
41.txt|44|1 > 41.txt
```

Change `" > "` to just `>` to actually create the output files when done testing.

The leading awk|sort|cut groups all of the input lines by the file name ($1) so that the final awk is only processing content for 1 output file at a time so it only has 1 output file open at a time and so won't fail with a "too many open file names" error once a dozen or so output files are created in non-gawk or run slower due to juggling opening/closing output files with gawk.

Here's what's happening at each of the earlier stages that set up the data for the final awk script to be able to parse it while only having 1 output file open at a time and retaining the original input order on a per output file name basis:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {print (NR>1), $1, NR, $0}' a.txt
0|filename|1|filename|count|age
1|1.txt|2|1.txt|1|15
1|1.txt|3|1.txt|2|14
1|2.txt|4|2.txt|3|1
1|41.txt|5|41.txt|44|1
1|2.txt|6|2.txt|1|3
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {print (NR>1), $1, NR, $0}' a.txt |
    sort -t'|' -k1,1n -k2,2 -k3,3n
0|filename|1|filename|count|age
1|1.txt|2|1.txt|1|15
1|1.txt|3|1.txt|2|14
1|2.txt|4|2.txt|3|1
1|2.txt|6|2.txt|1|3
1|41.txt|5|41.txt|44|1
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {print (NR>1), $1, NR, $0}' a.txt |
    sort -t'|' -k1,1n -k2,2 -k3,3n |
    cut -d'|' -f4-
filename|count|age
1.txt|1|15
1.txt|2|14
2.txt|3|1
2.txt|1|3
41.txt|44|1
```